# 16.10 Server - update-rc.d not creating symlinks for vncserver

Tags: server, startup, 16.10, symbolic-link

**Sorry - edited to clarify that this is Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) NOT 14.10.

For some reason 14.10 was stuck in my head.**

I am trying to setup a headless VNC server and using this guide as a reference:

https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04

It mostly seems to work, but `vncserver` is failing to start on boot, starts manually ok.

When I run

```
update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99
```

I am supposed to get something like:

```
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vncserver ...
/etc/rc0.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc1.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc6.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc2.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc3.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc4.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
/etc/rc5.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
```

Which I am assuming is the symlink being created

Whereas, I get nothing back. Command completes without any error or feedback...

So have gone looking for the symlinks:

```
ls -al /etc/rc?.d/
```

Shows me no `vncserver` symlinks created at all. So I am supposing this is why it is not starting.

I have removed and re-added, re-wrote the script....

Is there any logging for `update-rc.d` that might tell me what's (not) going on?

I guess I can create these links manually, but I have no clue how to do so...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you really use 14.10 (which is no longer supported for almost two years now) or is that just a typo in your question title?

Comment: Sorry - well spotted @ByteCommander - was a typo, I meant 16.10, sorry.

Comment: ... and sorry @user535733 to have mislead you - I  now know more about the differences between Upstart and SystemD tho'

Comment: @user535733 Its in /etc/init.d and executable.

Comment: Does the script in /etc/init.d have LSB headers (https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)?

Comment: The script I am using is in the howto I have linked. It seems to support some of the Init script actions, if that what LSB headers refers to. Otherwise I am not sure/

Comment: anyone got any thought? @user535733 - thanks !

Comment: Similar scenario but in my case the same scripts are registered correctly in 16.04 but not in 16.10

Answer (score 7):

#### LSB Headers required on 16.10 ?

Similar problem for me - my scripts where registering correctly with 16.04 but not with 16.10. I added the LSB headers and it started working correctly with 16.10

I used something similar to the example below, adding it after the #!/bin/sh line

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       my_service
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts my_service
# Description:       starts my_service using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO
```